# Mobile Menu behind image

Tags: html, css, mobile

My website's mobile menu shows the menu behind the image.

However, on my phone (Samsung s21 ultra) - it shows fine and the menu is in front

Any advice?

Comment: have you tried z-index?

Comment: Can you provide us some code?

Comment: The most likely problem is that you are using some CSS property that isn't supported in Safari/IOS but we can't tell without seeing the relevant code. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can visit the w3school documentation [Link Mobile Navigation Menu](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_mobile_navbar.asp), although there needs to be a little change at least it can be used as a reference to create a slide menu on your mobile display.